# How do I implement a javascript clock?

Tags: javascript

This code is taken from a Udemy course to make projects. I have seen this code work perfectly before and now it shows nothing. All it does is reflect the local time. It remains blank.

I have run it through a couple of browsers and ran it on codepen and it all looks the same, which is blank. I had codepen analyze the code for errors and it came clean on the html, css, and javascript portions.

https://codepen.io/Laurax/pen/gVwGYo

here is the javascript portion by itself:

```
 setInterval(function (){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = cuttentTime.getSeconds();
    var period = "AM";

     if(hours >= 12){
     period = "PM";
    }
    if(hours > 12){
    hours = hours -12;
    }
    if(seconds < 10){
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    if(minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

   var clockTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + period;
   var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
   clock.innerText = clockTime;

   }, 1000 );
```

I expect the output to show hours, minutes, and seconds. It should be white numbers over a black background.

Comment: cuttentTime is not defined.

Comment: Yes typo error ! Should be close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in this line:

`var seconds = cuttentTime.getSeconds();`

Your date variable is called `currentTime` and not `cuttentTime`.